# starting a spring 3.0 application

Tags: spring

i stated a new spring project in the STS
add a new spring configuration (it generate it automatically):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


</beans>
```

and i get the next error message from the STS:

> Error occured processing XML 'null'. See Error Log for more details

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a STS bug. Take a look at

[STS-2180](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2180) 
 **Status** : open 
**Resolution** : Unresolved

**Edit**
**Adi Mor** Found a solution from the spring forum : need to disable the Cache in the eclipse:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections -> Cache -> Disable caching
```

Comment: thanks alot i found a solution :)
the solution in the spring forum

need to disabled the Cache in the eclipse: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections -> Cache -> Disable caching